# How to escape output in PHP

Tags: php, security, escaping, xss

I am a newbie, just to be clear. I hear a lot about escaping data to prevent XSS attacks. How do I actually do that?

This is what I am doing currently -

```
$s = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['name']));
```

Is this enough? Thanks

Comment: You need tell us what you are doing with the data. Are you inserting it into a database? Or outputting it on a web site? Every thing you do with the data requires a different form of sanitation.

Comment: @pekoe both....in one file I accept and insert...the other...I output.

Comment: Consider that now I am going to insert the $s in the database. Is it secure enough?

Comment: It depends. Show some of the code you are using to insert the data into the database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you output the data to html you should use **htmlspecialchars()**
else, if you're storing the data in a database you should escape **strings** using mysqli_real_escape_string() and cast numbers (or use prepared statements for both)
and protect identifiers/operators by whitelist-based filtering whem.

Both these methods are all you need if you use them the correct way.

Comment: Edited your answer to make it helpful

Answer (score 5):

You should use **[htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)** for output rather than **mysqli_real_escape_string**.

Comment: @Chrism by output he means **the same output** you've asked for. Check your question title for reminder.

Comment: Output, in this case, means "Stuff that gets put into an HTML document as HTML" (as opposed to, say, JavaScript). It doesn't matter if you use echo, print, `<?=` or something else.

Comment: Yeah, when you output untrusted data to the database, you use `mysqli_real_escape_string($something)` or `$pdo->quote($something)` or prepared statements. When you output untrusted data to the user via echoing something into the html page he/she receives, you use `htmlspecialchars($something, ENT_QUOTES);`

Comment: @Carlos that is an answer everyone expects.

Comment: @Chrism to avoid lots of security holes (but not all can be avoided by this), you need to escape the data you output to the medium. And every medium has different output rules, so for the database you use one set of functions, for the html/xml another, to use untrusted data to exec processes on the server another different... Long story short, every medium is different, so they need different functions

Comment: @Carlos you do not understand what escaping for. It's not not for "untrusted data" but for any data goes to database. Moreover, it's for **string** type data only, not for anything else. See accepted answer for details. That's very important thing to understand or get vulnerable code in seconds.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I understand what escaping is for, maybe I don't explained myself well. Yes, "untrusted data" may be a bit low. All data should be escaped before outputting it, but specially data that comes from the user: If I know some property is just an alphanumeric string then one really doesn't need to escape it, althougth it is best practice to do so (maybe in the future this property can hold any type of char, not just alphanumeric?)

Comment: @Carlos sure, that's what prepared statements indeed for - to make programmer not to think if the data is trusted or not, but make it syntactically correct unconditional, with no exceptions, excuses or assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting to fix your code against attacks (meaning **SQL Injection attacks**), you will be better of checking out parameterized queries. What you basically do with these is separate your content (input) from the commands (sql), so you can never have them confused by a possible mallicious user-entered piece of information like the name.

You can try starting with using the `PDO` class:
You can start reading the `PDO` manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and this page has a nice example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

However, you don't need to use `PDO`, you can use `mysqli` also, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
<?php
/* Script A -- We are already connected to the database */

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, 100)"); /* Query 1 */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $string, $integer);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); // CLOSE $stmt
?>
```

Because the name is a separate value, it can never be an SQL command, so you will be safe automatically.

Comment: added an example and some links for you :)

Comment: This prevents SQL injection attacks, not XSS attacks.

Comment: True. I think the origional questoin was about that, and @chrism was confused between the two, making me confused for a moment there too.