# How to HTML escape values for radio buttons in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

The CakePHP documentation does not cover the escaping of values when using FormHelper::radio().

Actually (in cakephp 2.4) it seems trying to set escape=true has no effect. Is there a better way than escaping the options manually?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way is to output text with `h()`.

Here they ask a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169051/902780