# How to loop through all Amazon API array Book results in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, amazon-product-api

I am trying to consume an Amazon Product API and I choose to search for books alone base on the user search query. However after converting the response to an array, I am having problem looping through all the result without having to specify an index.
Below is my Code:

```
  <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <?php 

          foreach($formattedResponse as $response) { 

            ?>

          <div class="col-md-8">            
          <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            <img class="card-img-top" data-src="" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text"></p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Arthur: <?php echo $response['Item'][0]['ItemAttributes']['Author']; ?></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Title: <?php echo $response['Item'][0]['ItemAttributes']['Title']; ?></button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">Price: <?php echo $response['Item'][0]['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['FormattedPrice']; ?> </small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <?php 

        } 
        ?>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Displaying the results works perfectly, the only drawback is, it fetches only the first index of the returned book response out of the thousands present because I used `$response['Item'][0]` if I take away the `[0]` from I get an error.. Below is the result

```
  Arthur: Harry Boone Porter
  Title: The Day of Light
  Price: $8.00
```

My Question:
The array contains [0],[1],[2] to [1000] How can I fetch all the book results in the above format instead of the first index which I am using.

Here is my Array Code Snippet: https://pasteio.com/xlsoTVWJLGBO

Comment: Please share more details. "The array contains [0],[1],[2] to [1000]" sounds strange, but not like a huge problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like formatted response is the named array and does not have to be iterated with foreach loop, if I'm not mistaken, you just need to:

1. Pass to the view not the *$formattedResponse* but *$formattedResponse['item']* and not to iterate through it. Lets call it *$items*.

> ```
> $items = $formattedResponse['item'];
> // pass $items to the view.
> ```

2. In *['item']* element you have an indexed array with numbers. So iterate through it

> ```
> <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
>     ... html here
>    <?= htmlspecialchars($item['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['FormattedPrice']) ?>
> <?php endforeach; ?>
> ```

Do not forget to escape output for your views. Use Twig, Blade or something like *Html::encode($var)* from Yii. [How to escape output in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141513/how-to-escape-output-in-php)

To make debugging of multidimensional large arrays easier install **larapack/dd** from composer, and add

```
 dd($largeArray)
```

in any place of your code. It's like var_dump, but a lot easier to look for human being ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I set item to the Formatted response Item Index. like this:
      $items = $formattedResponse['item'];
I get a warning. ('Invalid Item supplied for foreach'); How do I tackle that?

Comment: Could you dump the entire formatted response and add your new code to pasteio?

Comment: This is the link to the entire formatted array response: https://pasteio.com/xIiqnkWz5dR3

This is the link to my index page code: https://pasteio.com/xyhnfj4aCVQ2

Comment: And the link to the dumped version of the formatted response: https://pasteio.com/xt7f5Abrpb7I

Comment: I think you should examine your $formattedResponse's nodes more carefully: seems like you need to accees [Items][Item] node. Something like foreach ($formattedResponse['Items']['Item'] as $item). If it's hard to read such an amount, you have already required vendor/autoload in your project. Just install larapack/dd and dd($formattedResponse) instead of <pre> print_r() </pre> it will be way easier to debug your application, especially with such large arrays.

Comment: I have just installed larapack/dd, you're right everything looks easier. But the error still persist. "Invalid Item Supplied in foreach" here is the dd code link: https://pasteio.com/xFdSh2JVf1yA

Comment: Are you iterating through $formattedResponse['Items']['Item'] as $item? Just  be a little bolder, play with it)) dd($formattedResponse), save, reload. What node are you seeing next ? dd($formattedResponse->Items). Okay, nothing and a php warning, what's wrong? dd($formattedResponse['Items']. Another array. And so on until you get to the right node with the numbered indexes that you can iterate through.

Comment: Yes I am. When I declared $items = $formattedResponse['Items']['item']; and used the php is_array($items) function, I noticed everything disappeared. does it means that $formattedResponse['Items']['item'] isn't an array?

Comment: Okay, what does dd($formattedResponse['Items']['Item']) show ? Maybe it's because the first letter of ['item'] is in lower case ?

Comment: Yea! It returned all the items array. when I uses the Uppercase I

Comment: Yea, almost. just a little glitch. In between the response I am getting a little error in between, everything appears perfectly well. But the error keeps popping. Take a look.  https://pasteio.com/xz58yYRCpdYt

Comment: The Undefined Index ListPrice Error keeps showing even when the index is correct. I have cross checked it to ensure that the nodes are right, but the error still shows.